Cocoapod integration Issue in Framework as target
I have created an Application in which we have framework as target. I am using SendbirdChatSDK and Sendbirdcalls Cocoapod as dependency for framework. While compiling it is showing error in swift generated header as Module not found for Sendbirdcalls and SendbirdChatSDK.
Note: Our Project has mixed Objective C and Swift
Please find screenshot and Project link for reference: 
Github link :(https://github.com/shikha110225/POCAPP)
I have tried adding Cocoapod for the framework. Added the .h file in bridging header.
Also tried deleting derived data.
Expectation : Code should compile after this
